Is there some physical limitation that causes all induction cooktops to be just one coil?
In my searches online, it seems that all induction cooktops have just one coil. My question is why isn't a multi coil design possible? I've drawn a little image below to illustrate what I mean. I know there exist some wireless chargers like that, so I guess I just don't understand why there aren't any cooktops.

I feel like it would have some insane benefits to induction cooktops, especially in evenness of cooking and allowing weirdly shaped cookware. If you could toggle each one individually, you could shrink them a lot and cook any flat bottomed pot. It seems so obvious to me that I must be missing something. Is there some reason other than cost that these don't exist?
Edit to address some comments
While certainly normal coils work just fine in a lot of cases, there are some instances where having many would be helpful. In carbon steel pans and cast iron especially, the heat is not distributed super well, so having even heating to start could help.
Take a look at this photo:

You can see that a ring in the center is browner than the rest, and importantly, the inside of the ring is less cooked. This leads me to believe that even for circular pans, it could be good to have many coils.
Edit 2
Now that I'm thinking about it, having a high resolution set of coils would also help cook low heat foods. Currently, a lot of cooktops will just switch on and off. With multiple, you could stagger it to ensure more consistent heating.

a 2d pot won't be much use. My pots are 3d... As for a single coil, my induction top has 4 with independent controls, with 2 that can be combined together.

Any pot with a flat bottom haha, misspoke

I guess my question is more specifically, why aren't there "high resolution" cooktops, ie more complex than just two that combine.

Cost - engineers could design them and control them but would the increase in performance warrant it and would the accountants sign off or would the customers pay?

Hmm, that is interesting to me, given that the breville control freak sells for 1500 and seems to be decently popular. I guess if there's nothing physically stopping people from building these, I just have to wait for the market to grow.

I think methods to improve the even distribution of heat will definitely be developed even at the cost of complexity and engineering challenges; however multiple coils might not be the easiest way to go about it.
The first thing is that smaller coils require higher frequency to deliver the same power. Higher frequency means more emf into the environment and more legal regulation issues/restrictions with the FCC or other regulating body.
There is also some physical required thickness of glass or material between the coil and the pan. Lets say the thickness is 6mm (1/4inch). The field strength 6mm away from a 300mm (12inch) is pretty good with minimal field getting recirculated through this 6mm gap. If the coils are 30mm though, this 6mm becomes appreciable and a significantly lower percent of the power is delivered to the pan. Think of the boundary of each coil as a re circulation loss; and the small coils have significantly more boundary distance than the one large coil.
A better way would probably be to purchase (or design) a better pan coil system. While we treat the pans separate from the induction cook top; they are very interconnected. The engineers on both ends have to make very large performance compromising assumptions about how their system will be used. If there was a standard among manufacturers, or if you could purchase both from the same company I think the heat distribution could be quite good.

If the benefits really were "insane" someone would have done it, for an appropriate price.
But since pots don't have unusual shapes, just round, oval, or rectangular, the need is not there to begin with.
Bosch FlexInduction combines multiple smaller coils when large pots are used, so that you better heat large pots. However, there's no need to cover exactly the whole surface of a pot, as you suggest, since the metal can spread heat to some degree.
So, optimal heating (only upon need) of rectangular pans is available by combining two zones, and more is unneeded.

No one wants a 24 point controller for more money when they can turn one knob.  Cost of an item is an appropriate engineering spec.  I think you need to spend time in the House of Quality, where most people's pots and pans are just shaped like pots pans.  Good product meet a consumer need, not extra specs for fun.

My idea was that it would auto detect which burners should be on, since individual ones can already do that. If they had temperature sensors, it could also ensure even heating across the pan.

@Suop "sensors for even heating" but some have sensors to detect empty pans and turn off after some time to avoid fires - a really smart idea

@Suop that would work, but you need customer demand for it.  Induction cooktops are already quite expensive.
